# Derivative of circumradius

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $P = \{p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2 - \mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ be a set of $n$ distinct points. Define the function $f: \mathbb{R}\times\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}^+$ by
$$(t,0)\mapsto \text{radius of the smallest enclosing circle of $P\cup\{(t,0)\}$}$$

Is this function of class $C^1$? Note that the metric is the Euclidean metric.

Comment: I assume you mean $P \cup \{ (t,0) \}$. The answer is no. Consider the case $P = \{ (0,1), (0,-1) \}$. It is easy to see the circumradius is 1 when $|t| \le 1$ and not differentiable at $t = \pm 1$.

Comment: Actually I find for your example
$$ r(t) = \frac{1+t^2}{2t}$$
for $\vert t \vert > 1$ ($r(t) = 1$ otherwise) which is $\mathcal C^1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending my comment, the "circumradius" is not $C^1$. In general, it is piecewise $C^{\infty}$. In fact, its square is a piecewise rational function in $t$.

For any finite set of points $X = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, let $\mathscr{R}(X)$ be the circumradius of $X$. ie. the minimal radius of circle containing all points in $X$.
In particular, for singletons $\{a\}$ or pair of points $\{a,b\}$, we have/define:

$$\mathscr{R}(\{a\}) = 0\quad\text{ and }\quad\mathscr{R}(\{a,b\}) = \frac{|a-b|}{2}$$

It is easy to verify the circumradius of $X$ is determined by the circumradius of its subsets of $3$ or fewer elements:

$$\mathscr{R}(X) = \max_{(a,b,c) \in X^3}\mathscr{R}(\{a,b,c\})\tag{*}$$

To understand how $\mathscr{R}(X)$ behaves, it just suffices to look at
the dependence of $\mathscr{R}(\{a,b,c\})$ upon $a,b,c$. Let us consider
the special case $a = (0,1), b = (0,-1)$ and $c = (x,y)$ where $x, y \ge 0$.
There are 3 possible subcases:

- $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$, $c$ falls inside the circle defined by $a,b$ and 
  $$\mathscr{R}(\{a,b,c\}) = \mathscr{R}(\{a,b\}) = 1.$$
- $x^2 + y^2 > 1$ and $y \ge 1$, $a$ falls inside the circle defined by $b,c$ and $$\mathscr{R}(\{a,b,c\}) = \mathscr{R}(\{b,c\}) = \frac12\sqrt{x^2 + (y+1)^2}.$$
- $x^2 + y^2 > 1$ and $0 \le y < 1$, with a little bit of geometry, one can show
  $$\mathscr{R}(\{a,b,c\}) = \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{x^2 + y^2 - 1}{2 x}\right)^2}$$

This means if we fix $a,b$ and let $c$ moves along a straight line $c(t) = (x_0,y_0) + t (x',y')$,
$\mathscr{R}(\{a,b,c(t)\})$ will be a function composed of pieces of 3 possible
forms:

- a constant.
- $\sqrt{P_2(t)}$ - square root of a quadratic function in $t$.
- $\frac{\sqrt{P_4(t)}}{P_1(t)}$ - square root of a $4$-th degree polynomial divided by a linear polynomial.

In short, $\mathscr{R}(\{a,b,c(t)\})^2$ will be a piecewise rational function in $t$.

Back to the original circumradius we want to study. Using $(*)$, we have:

$$\mathscr{R}(P\cup\{(t,0)\}) = \max\left(\mathscr{R}(P), \max_{(a,b)\in P^2}(\mathscr{R}(\{a,b,(t,0)\})\right)$$

This implies the square of the circumradius we want to calculate is the maximum of a bunch of piecewise rational functions in $t$.

Given any 2 rational functions $f(t), g(t)$, we know either $f(t) = g(t)$ for all $t$ or for finite many $t$. This implies the maximum of 2 piecewise rational functions is still a piecewise rational function.

From this, we can conclude $\mathscr{R}(P\cup\{(t,0)\})^2$ is a piecewise rational function and hence the circumradius we care, $\mathscr{R}(P\cup\{(t,0)\})$, is piecewise $C^{\infty}$.

**UPDATE**

About the assertion that the "circumradius" $r(t) = \mathscr{R}( P \cup \{ (t,0)\} )$ is not $C^1$. The counter-example I used before:

$$P = \{ (0,1), (0,-1) \}$$

didn't work. I failed to recognize in that case,

$$\lim_{t\to 1+} r'(t) = \lim_{t\to 1-} r'(t) = 0$$

In fact, for any 2 points $a, b$ and straight line $c(t) = (x_0,y_0) + t (x',y')$, The function $\mathscr{R}(\{a,b,c(t)\})$ is $C^1$ over $\mathbb{R}$ as long as  $a \ne b$ and $c(t)$ didn't intersect $a$ nor $b$.

This implies when $|P| = 2$, $r(t)$ is indeed $C^1$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

When $|P| = 3$, there are already examples that $r(t)$ fails to be $C^1$. However, those examples are hard to visualize. The simplest example I find is for $|P| = 4$ and the points
forms the corner of a square:

$$P = \{ (1,1), (1,-1), (-1,1), (-1,-1) \}$$

With a little bit of algebra, one can show:

$$r(t) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{(|t|+1)^2+1}{2(|t|+1)},&|t| \ge \sqrt{2}\\
    \sqrt{2}, & |t| \le \sqrt{2}
\end{cases}$$

Notice in this case,

$$\lim_{|t|\to\sqrt{2}+} |r'(t)| = \sqrt{2} - 1 \ne 0 = \lim_{|t|\to\sqrt{2}-} |r'(t)|$$

This means $r(t)$ fails to be differentiable at $t = \pm\sqrt{2}$ and hence is not $C^1$.

Comment: @roger Oops, I didn't notice in my counter-example, the $\lim_{t\to 1+} r'(t) = \lim_{t\to 1-} r'(t) = 0$. Let we think about that more.

Comment: Thanks for your counterexample! My intuition tells me that any failure to be differentiable may only occur when $t$ passes from being on the boundary of the smallest enclosing circle to being enclosed by the circle formed by two or three points of $P$. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: Your intuition sounds plausible but I don't think that is the case. When we change $t$ in $r(t) = \max\left( \mathscr{R}(P), \max_{(a,b)\in P^2}\mathscr{R}(\{a,b,(t,0)\}) \right)$, $r(t)$ can fail to be differentiable at $t$ where the $(a,b)$ responsible for the maximum in $r(t)$ jumps to a different pair $(a',b')$. If we add two extra points $(-\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{5}+\epsilon, \pm\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{5} )$ to our counterexample and increase $t$ to $\sqrt{2}$, the $(a,b)$ responsible for the maximum becomes $(-1,\pm 1)$. If increase $t$ slightly more, the $(a,b)$ changes to the two new points!

Comment: I agree that such jumps may be a problem but I have not yet been able to construct a counterexample.

Comment: The example I quoted before: $P = \{ (\pm 1,\pm 1), (-\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{5} + \epsilon, \pm \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{5} ) \}$ is a counterexample. e.g. when $\epsilon = 0.01$, $r'(t)$ jumps at $t \sim 1.57409429$ from $0.42453925$ to $0.45045098$.

Comment: Sorry about that, you were right of course. Thanks.